# Transferring of webpages to another host resulting in blank index

Tags: php, html, mysql

My index page is unable to work (showing blank page) when transferred to a new host. While my old host is working fine. I believe is the MySQL version/setting

I moved from v5.5 to v5

[image]

Take a look at the image above
If I were to remove that line of code, everything will be working fine however my register page is unable to work. What exactly went wrong; can anyone shed some light

Comment: Screenshot does not exist

Comment: @John did u verify your mysql username and password in conf? I think they are different than previous host

Comment: Screenshot is there! try again

Comment: I will try again... I don't think it's the config.php user pass problem

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and view your page to see if there's any errors

Comment: Nothing. Totally blank. I used it in my config.php

Comment: Is there any output in you error log file?

Comment: What PHP version is new host running as `PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE` available since PHP 5.2.0. And what do you mean `...my register page is unable to work`

Comment: @JohnTan I think codefreak is right. On some hosts, database names would start with your control panel username at their starting. Like `user5646_mp05`. Besides, you can get any error reported from PDO by `$error = $db->errorInfo();` and I suggest you to do that and see what's wrong. BTW, why did you put PDO creation in a `try` block while you're not catching the exception?